# Grep with multiple patterns used on the command

Tags: ssh, grep, logging, tail, cat

A few days ago I installed Centos 7 on my server and run ssh. Now I want to track logs. Is there anyway to combine cat or tail with grep to have clear failed and accepted login attempts list from a chosen day?

I know it won't work, but something like:

```
cat /var/log/secure | grep "Accepted" "Failed" "Today's date"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just:

```
grep '^\(Accepted\|Failed\) date' /var/log/secure
```

or:

```
grep -e Accepted -e Failed /var/log/secure | grep date
```