# How to grep multiple @ types?

Tags: linux, grep

I'm using Linux Centos 6-64.

**How can I change the following command**, which only retrieves emails written with @, inside an input folder:

`grep -E -o -r "[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}" /inputfolder/ | sort | uniq > "/outputfolder/result.txt"`

**to retrieve emails in all these @ formats below?**

```
info&#064;example.com
info@example.com
info(at)example.com
info[at]example.com
info%26%23064%3Bexample.com
info%40example.com
```

If possible command in one single line. Thank you

Comment: You can use groups like `(foo|bar)` instead of the literal `@`.

Comment: Decent start with formatting. Downvote revoked.

Comment: Hello Kamil, have formatted it, please let me know if you find it more pleasant now. By the way would you know what need to update in this command? Thanks

Comment: Hint: to address another user in a comment, the syntax is like @KamilMaciorowski . Please read "Replying in comments" section [here](https://superuser.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). The point is "Hello Kamil" won't send me any notification but "@Kamil" will.

Comment: Hello @slhck, thanks for replying. I changed @ by (foo|bar) in my example command then it didnt grep any email not even the ones with @'s...

Comment: Oh ok @KamilMaciorowski :)

Comment: Another hint: backslash at the very end of a line makes the shell parse the next line as if they were one line. I used this feature when I edited the question; common shells should understand and the readability for humans was improved. You changed it back and now it looks awful again. I won't fight over formatting, this is your question. I'm just letting you know my edit shouldn't have broken the command.

Comment: Joao, obviously, you should not use `(foo|bar)`, as that will only match if someone literally typed `foo` or `bar`. That was just an example. You need to replace `foo` and `bar` with the respective alternatives for the `@` that you want to capture.

Comment: Hello @slhck, thanks for replying. I replaced the @ by the following: *(@|(at)|[at]|&#064;|%40|%26%23064%3B)* and all of them except (at) and [at] are working, should I add something else? Thanks

Comment: @Kamil how do you put the colored background formatting inside this little comments such as the (foo|bar) written above with colored background?

Comment: See my last edit to the question. Such backticks work in comments as well.

Comment: Hi @Kamil, I didnt notice you had changed it, it might have been when I was testing how to format in same time you were formatting it as well.

Comment: OK, no harm done. When it comes to formatting of questions and answers you may click "edit" on another well-formatted posts and learn from how other users did it (then you discard your changes, if any). With comments it's not as easy, but you have [this](https://superuser.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). `Code in backticks` is there.

Comment: @Kamil ok thanks. By the way, do you know how do I add the `(at)` and `[at]` in the `(foo|bar)` example above in the command line which I changed to `(@|(at)|[at]|&#064;|%40|%26%23064%3B)` ? But its not grepping the `(at)` and `[at]` . Thanks

Comment: `()` and `[]` have special meaning to regex. I *guess* you need to escape them: `(@|\(at\)|\[at\]|&#064;|%40|%26%23064%3B)`.

Comment: @Kamil, its grepping the `[at]` and `(at)` with the backslashes but disappearing with whats before the `@` on those emails, and also disappearing with whats before the  `&#064;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grep with multiple patterns used on the command](https://superuser.com/questions/1112366/grep-with-multiple-patterns-used-on-the-command)

Comment: @phuclv thanks for replying, I read your example however I couldnt find a way to use it on mine here. I am only needing now to know how to write `[at]` and `(at)` inside this `(foo|bar)` without problems in the regex.

Comment: you can grep multiple formats at once like `grep -e "format1" -e "format2" ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `-P` flag for perl regex and `-i` for case insensitive:

```
grep -Pi "[A-Z0-9][\w.%+-]+(?:@|&#064;|\(at\)|\[at\]|%26%23064%3B|%40)[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}"
```

`\w` stands for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

**Explanation:**

```
[A-Z0-9]            : 1 alphanum
[\w.%+-]+           : 1 or more alphanum, _, ., %, + or -
(?:                 : start non capture group
    @               : literally @
  |                 : OR
    &#064;          : html entity for @
  |                 :
    \(at\)          :
  |                 :
    \[at\]          :
  |                 :
    %26%23064%3B    :
  |                 :
    %40             :
)                   :
[A-Z0-9]            : 1 alphanum
[A-Z0-9.-]+         : 1 or more alphanum, . or -
\.                  : a dot
[A-Z]{2,6}          : 2 upto 6 alpha (be aware that TLDs may have much more characters, see: https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
grep -Pi "[A-Z0-9][\w.%+-]+(?:@|&#064;|\(at\)|\[at\]|%26%23064%3B|%40)[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}" file.txt

info&#064;example.com
info@example.com
info(at)example.com
info[at]example.com
info%26%23064%3Bexample.com
info%40example.com
```

Comment: @Joao: you have to add `-or` options so it becomes `grep -Pior ....` if you want to grep all files recursively and output only the matched part.